# Matlab multiple exponential curve fitting to same set of coefficients

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting, model-fitting

I'm trying to fit multiple exponential curves to pairs of data using the same set of coefficients for 'exp1' fitting method, which would produce something like this:
[image: graph]

Example data is as follows:

```
timeToFit = [24 48;48 72];
dataToFit = [150000 230000;105000 430000];
```

I can fit the data using individual fitting equations as follows:

```
f1=fit([timeToFit(1,1),timeToFit(1,2)]'[dataToFit(1,1),dataToFit(1,2)]','exp1');
f2=fit([timeToFit(2,1),timeToFit(2,2)]'[dataToFit(2,1),dataToFit(2,2)]','exp1');
```

I attempted to perform the fitting in a for loop but I got the error "conversion to 'double' from 'cfit' is not possible". I coded this as follows:

```
collatedTime = [0,0,24,24,48,48,72,72];
for j = 1:size(collatedTime,2)/2-2
    f = fit([timeToFit(j,1),timeToFit(j,2)]',[dataToFit(j,1),dataToFit(j,2)]','exp1');
    plot(f)
end
```

What I would like is to create a fitting function that is capable of fitting an exponential curve between however many pairs of data I have like in the figure above, using a single set of coefficients for the fit and taking into account the decrease in y at each x value (i.e. fit the same curve to each set of data). How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Shows us the code that doesnt work

Comment: Please see edited post

Comment: Which line of code throws that error?

Comment: Per [the documentation for `fit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html#outputarg_fitobject), "See [Fit Postprocessing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit-postprocessing.html) for functions for plotting, evaluating, calculating confidence intervals, integrating, differentiating, or modifying your fit object."

Comment: f = fit([timeToFit(j,1),timeToFit(j,2)]',[dataToFit(j,1),dataToFit(j,2)]','exp1');

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for the error to come from that line with the code you've provided. Have you preallocated `f` somewhere?

Comment: I attempted to preallocate using an array of zeros - f = zeros(size(collatedTime,2)/2-2,2); - however this gave the error "The following error occurred converting from cfit to double:
Conversion to double from cfit is not possible."

Comment: If you want to create an array of `cfit` objects then you'll need to use a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html). `zeros` creates a `double` array, and you can't assign an object to a `double` array. Some objects have their own array types and/or built-in conversion methods, but the error message is clearly telling you that `cfit` isn't one of them.